# how to make new data to be default type or default value (instead of nan) in pandas.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm dynamicly constructing a df with pandas.
where i wish the new data(element) when is added default to be a specific type or value, instead of nan. could this be possible?
like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.at[1,["a","b","c"]] = "a"
df.at[2,["a","c"]] = "b"
print(df)
```

you got:

```
   a    b  c
1  a    a  a
2  b  NaN  b
```

where df.at[2,"b"] is set by pd default as "nan", but i wish it could default to be empty string("");

i don't want to use pd.isna() or replace() to check and assign value in each loop when i dynamicly create this df;

is there a way, like set this pd to be string type when initial the pd?
like:
`df = pd.DataFrame(dtype=str)`
(which i tried and seemed no work)

---update---

the full code is something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for loop:
   df.at[1,["a","b"]] = "a"
   df.at[2,["a"]] = "b"
   x = df.at[2,"b"] + "hi"
```

where line of `x` is error(float type + string type), if i don't use some `if/else` to check `nan` before.
in this case, i think `df.fillna("")` is much better than `isna()/replace()` but still a little bit limit.
thx again:)

Answer (score 2):

How about using `df.fillna("")` after the dataframe creation. In this way you fill the nan value with a specified value.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = ["a","b","c"]
df['b'] = ["a","c", np.nan]
df = df.fillna("")
```

Then, you get this

```
   a  b
0  a  a
1  b  c
2  c
```

Comment: thanks but the full code is something like:
```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for loop:
df.at[1,["a","b"]] = "a"
df.at[2,["a"]] = "b"
x = df.at[2,"b"] + "hi"
```
where line of `x` is error(float type + string type), if i don't use some `if/else` to check `nan` before.  
in this case, i think `df.fillna("")` is much better than `isna()/replace()` but still a little bit limit.
thx again:)